# Positioning using Z-Index

Tags: css, z-index

Can we position one HTML element above another element using z-Index ?
Eg :

```
<div>One</div>
<div>Five</div>
```

Now one should be above five....

my question may be very basic but.........

Answer (score 3):

Give the element that you need to show on top a higher z index value.

```
<div style='z-index: 2'>first</div>
<div style='z-index: 1'>second</div>
```

Read

[Specifying the stack level: the 'z-index' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index)

Answer (score 1):

for z-index to work you need to have `position` set to absolute, relative or fixed for each div you want layered, you can then position the two elements above each other using `left` and `top` attributes.

The higher the z-index the 'higher' the div is. ie, `z-index:1` with be above `z-index:0`, think of it as a stack of transparent sheets coming out of your screen towards you.

more info here:

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not what you're asking but the whole point of using `z-index` is positioning one HTML element above another.

You can have more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/understanding_css_z-index).

Answer (score 0):

give the three different divs a unique id like:

```
<div id="divOne">One</div>
<div id="divTwo">Two</div>
<divid="divThree">Three</div>
```

in your css stylesheet:

```
#divOne {position:absolute;z-index:1;}
#divTwo {position:absolute;z-index:2;}
#divThree {position:absolute;z-index:3;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same the z-index the less the preference of it as compared to the other layers. That is, a layer with z-index=2 will be rendered above a layer of z-index=1.

```
<div style='position:absolute;z-index:2'>first</div>
<div style='position:absolute;z-index:1'>second</div>
```